# Enable Firewall in Ubuntu

Tags: unity

Hi I am running apache server in my desktop which does contain security issues so I want to  enable How to enable firewall in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Take a look at [Ubuntu Firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/firewall.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ufw
sudo ufw enable
```

ufw is probably already installed but it doesn't hurt to try and install it if it is. The last command enables the default firewall settings. For more info on using ufw I recommend this post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1893751 You should get a pretty good idea on how to set rules from the information covered on the topic.

A much easier way to govern your firewall rules is to install gufw which is a frontend GUI to ufw.

```
sudo apt-get install gufw
```

You can search for "gufw" or "firewall" in your apps directory or in Gnome Shell I believe it's listed under settings.

[image]
picture taken from http://www.noobslab.com/2013/10/tweaksthings-to-do-after-install-of.html